# AngularJS trying to use nested state from external module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got some err when i try to create external module, i think that is something wrong with my nested state in nested.js

The err said:Error: State 'admin.quyensudung' has a 'views' object. It cannot also have "view properties" at the state level.  Move the following properties into a view (in the 'views' object):  controller

Please help me fix this bug and tell me the reason i got this bug thank too much

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngCookies',
  'quyensudung',
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');

$stateProvider

    .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        templateUrl: 'admin/home/index.html'
}])
```

nested.js

```
var quyensudung = angular.module('quyensudung', [])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('admin.quyensudung', {
            url: '/quyensudung',
            views: {
                "container@": {
                    templateUrl: 'admin/quyensudung/index.html'
                },
            },
            controller: 'quyensudungController',        
        })
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: State 'admin.quyensudung' has a 'views' object. It cannot also have "view properties" at the state level. Move the following properties into a view

Just move `controller: 'quyensudungController',` into `views` `->` `"container@"`

Instead:

```
.state('admin.quyensudung', {
        url: '/quyensudung',
        views: {
            "container@": {
                templateUrl: 'admin/quyensudung/index.html'
            },
        },
        controller: 'quyensudungController',        
    })
```

Should be:

```
.state('admin.quyensudung', {
        url: '/quyensudung',
        views: {
            "container@": {
                templateUrl: 'admin/quyensudung/index.html',
                controller: 'quyensudungController'
            },
        }     
    })
```

Ref: [Nested-States-and-Nested-Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#view-inherited-resolved-dependencies)